# Are auxiliary fuel tanks optional on the Boeing 737 Max 9?

Tags: airline-operations, boeing-737, fuel

Does the  Boeing 737 Max 9 have auxiliary fuel tanks like the Boeing  737-900ER? And have any airlines ordered them without if optional?

Answer (score 1):

Aux fuel is optional on the Max 9, but to find out who has ordered aircraft with and without you will have to coax that information from Boeing or the airlines operating them.